# CodeIgniter project has over 8000 issues in SonarQube

Tags: php, codeigniter, sonarqube, codeigniter-2

When running [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org) on a [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) project I get over 8000 issues all regarding CodeIgniter code. What to do? I like working with CodeIgniter but would also like to be able to check my code with SonarQube.

One option is to fix all the issues in CodeIgniter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you probably need to look at their documentation or plugins. Im not familiar with it

Comment: what types of issues does it tell you it has?

Comment: `When running sonarcube on a codeigniter project i get over 8000 issues...` Are you referring to an unmodified system folder or the application code which someone else wrote? Either way, if you don't know PHP then hire someone who does because it is absurd to ask for `One option is to fix all the issues...`

Comment: im talking about the basic framwork of codeigniter. I have fixed already 4000 issues

Comment: "exit(...)" and "die(...)" statements should not be used 147 
"&&" and "||" should be used 8 
Method arguments with default value should be last 6 
Switch cases should end with an unconditional break statement 1 
Local variable and function parameter names should comply with a naming convention 609 
Statements should be on separate lines

Comment: wy the downvote?? Qustion not clear?

Comment: [The OP is absurd and off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  We know nothing about these issues and you're simply asking us if you should fix them.  Yes, write proper PHP code and follow [CodeIgniter's recommended code style guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html) or ignore SonarQube, is basically the only answer to this.  Otherwise, we're here for very specific code questions, not _general_ discussions or opinions about whether or not to fix 8000 various unknown issues.

Comment: I was hoping that someone working with Codeigniter has run into the same problem and had a recommendation how to solve it. Im talking about 8k issues in the basic framework of Codeigniter, no third party code involved yet. Its only absurd if you think its absurd.

Comment: It's even more absurd that you're asking about the code inside the framework itself, something you should never be editing.

Comment: whys is that absurd if sonarqube report these issues? btw, i fixed over 90% of them

Answer (score 0):

I don't know CodeIgniter very well, but if there is generated and/or third party code that you want to exclude from the analysis, please have a look at [the exclusion settings in SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).